# Curse on the Kennedys

Tags: curse, story-identification

I once heard that a Rabbi cursed the Kennedy family because a member of that family who was involved with US immigration turned away a boat of Jewish immigrants. I would like to know the source of that story and whether a theurgical curse was performed.

Answer (score 6):

Rabbi Berel Wein writes [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=107):

> The story of the alleged curse is pure legend, fabricated after Kennedy was running for President. In any event, Jews don't put curses on anybody. You should vote for whomever you feel to be the better person and candidate and will represent moral and Torah interests. In any event, I have sometimes felt that helping a person attain public office is in itself a form of revenge against that person.
>
> Rabbi Berel Wein