# The Mekor Baruch's intructions of making gold from copper

Tags: history, technology, story-identification, gold

Rav Epstein in his Mekor Baruch 3:19:6 brings a story about him and a maggid. The maggid was looking for a certain sefer which instructs one how to make gold from copper. The Mekor Baruch (who had the sefer) then strikes a deal with the maggid that if he follows the instructions and they indeed work then they will split the profit 70 (maggid) 30 (Rav Epstein). However, after he gave the maggid the instructions the maggid passed away and Rav Epstein felt that he was now able to publicize the instructions. He never tried it but gave his blessing to one who decides to try it.

Has anyone ever practically followed the instructions and tried it? Is this documented anywhere?

The text of the Mekor Baruch:

[image]
[image]

Instructions loosely translated:

**The instructions:**  Take 9 chicken eggs and place them in a pot, then cover the pot very well, then place it under a garbage heap for 30 days or more, then open each egg up and there will be a worm in each, return everything to another pot and cover it, the worms will then grow and eat everything and then they will begin to eat each other until one big worm remains, then burn this worm in the pot in a manner where you are far away from the bad smell since it is like a deadly poison, afterwards you will be left with ashes and you should take it and store it, after that take pure copper and melt it and place some of the ash on it and then you will have gold.

Comment: I am willing to try but I need the exact translation/details ((I can buy .9999 pure copper I can get natural eggs (not farm raised) the bugs might be different depending on location)

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/34179 is the book he had

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: DoubleAA  page 68

Comment: @DoubleAA , why isnt this on topic?

Comment: @hazoriz the worms are natural it seems

Comment: @sam The nature of the place (and of the chicken) (and the temperature) might change them

Comment: It seems the garbage is for the temperature and humidity , but what is "very well" in the pot and what is the everything that they eat before they ear each other (is it just the leftovers of the egg, or was there other things in the sir), what is the difference between sir and kdira (סיר קדרה)

Comment: Can someone explain why this isn't on topic,this question is asking if someone actually used the instructions of a particular sefer.

Comment: The question is about alchemy. This is not on topic. Perhaps more appropriate for skeptics stack exchange.

Comment: Absolutely not,it's a about a segulah brought by sefer of segulos,and is sourced in a famous book the Mekor Baruch,this is a very legitimate Jewish question,just like "does a hamsa or red string ward off the evil eye".There are many questions on here which are really off topic,this question is not one of them.

Comment: Your telling me this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61746/curse-on-the-kennedys/61754#61754 is more on topic than mine,you gotta be kidding me

Comment: I don't see anything in the question about Segulot or Judaism. It's just two Jews trying to figure out how to get rich. If you can explain what Judaism has to do with this, that would go a long way to making it on topic.

Comment: If I try this and post it on YouTube will that count as a documented attempt?:)

Comment: Yes,.....certainly :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as per http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67239/the-mekor-baruchs-intructions-of-making-gold-from-copper#comment189335_67239.

Comment: @DoubleAA I get the sense that the author believed this to be a "*segula*," i.e.  a *kabala*-based manipulation of the natural world. If so, then he believed that he was transmitting Judaism knowledge.

Comment: https://wapo.st/2wsBD4m